# ImageResizer.ImageBuilder giving error of Could not load type 'System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment' .Net core MVC 6

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-core-webapi, imageresizer

I am trying to resizing my image if its extension is among .jpg, .jpeg, .png or .webp.
below is my code

```
if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(newFileName).ToLower() == ".jpg" || System.IO.Path.GetExtension(newFileName).ToLower() == ".png" || System.IO.Path.GetExtension(newFileName).ToLower() == ".jpeg" || System.IO.Path.GetExtension(newFileName).ToLower() == ".webp")
                {
                    var path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, CMSUserAreaDir, "content_media/raw/" + newFileName);
                    var image = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file, path, new ImageResizer.Instructions("maxwidth=1920"), false, false);
                    string a = ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(image).FinalPath;
                }
```

and I'm getting this error
[image]
Anyone please help me to know what I'm doing wrong.
Thanks in advance.

I am not sure if I am missing any packages in my setup for this to happen, or I am not supposed to use ImageJob in this manner.

When I'm looking at packages for ImageResizer its shows message like this
[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above issue is resolved.
note that ImageResizer is not compatible with .net 6 yet, maybe it will in future.
Till then there are many alternatives available, I've used SixLabors.Imagesharp to resolved my issue.
here is updated code :

```
var path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath, CMSUserAreaDir, "content_media/raw/" + newFileName);
                //var image = new ImageResizer.ImageJob(file, path, new ImageResizer.Instructions("maxwidth=1920"), false, false);
                //string a = ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(image).FinalPath;
                using (var image = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream()))
                {
                    if (image.Width > 1920)
                    {
                        image.Mutate(x => x.Resize(new ResizeOptions
                        {
                            Size = new Size(1920, 0),
                            Mode = ResizeMode.Max
                        }));
                    }

                    image.Save(path);
                }
```

you need to add these packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="SixLabors.ImageSharp" Version="3.0.0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I created ImageResizer and Imageflow. You should use Imageflow.Net on .NET 6. ImageResizer is for legacy
.NET.

Imageflow .NET Server is generally the best thing to use for during-a-request image processing since it ships with proper disk caching, but Imageflow.Net offers the equivalent to ImageResizer's .Build method.